# Finding all files -- No such device error is output when piping

Tags: linux, bash, find

I wrote a short bash script to find all files in a directory and it's subdirectories, sort them based on size, and only output the first 10 lines. The meat of the script is the following:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n $lines | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs du -aSh
total=`du -h | tail -n 1 | cut -f1`
```

The second line outputs the total size. I wrote this a while ago I actually don't remember why I used du at the end to output each file.

This script works fine in my home, but when I try to run it in my working spaces, I get the following output and the script freezes, forcing me to Cntl-C:

> find: ./.OldFiles/.OldFiles: No such device

In my working space, there is a .OldFiles directory that is updated every 24 hours. An `ls -a` will not show it. I think it's a link to another space, but somehow find is tripping on .OldFiles/.OldFiles. EDIT: .OldFiles is actually a mounted filesystem, not a link.

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n"
```

This works just find on the command line, but piping it seems to be where the error occurs:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr
```

will fail.

I tried using an exclusion on the `.OldFiles` path, but I get the same output:

```
>find . -type f ! -path "*.OldFiles/*"
find: ./.OldFiles/.OldFiles: No such device
```

Can anyone help me out here? I can't find a way to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just want to negate a path, because `find` will keep checking its subdirectories, you want to `-prune` it.

So try something like this

```
find . -path './.OldFiles' -prune -o -type f -print
```

Which gets treated logically as

```
find . (-path './.OldFiles' AND -prune) OR (-type f AND -print)
```

Comment: That works. I'm getting a warning, now:  

find: WARNING: Hard link count is wrong for .: this may be a bug in your filesystem driver.  Automatically turning on find's -noleaf option.  Earlier results may have failed to include subdirectories that should have been searched.

Googling this lead me to try -xdev, -mount, and -fstype local, but I'm still getting the warning.

Comment: @user2824895 Yeah, `find` sometimes likes to complain about some filesystem types. Wouldn't worry about it too much, and throwing a `-noleaf` in there should get rid of the warning `find . -noleaf -path './.OldFiles' -prune -o -type f -print`. (Note `-noleaf` is an option and not a test, so it gets switched on at parse time, and ergo it doesn't really matter on what side of the `-o` you put it, it will always be true).